# Is it possible to put a marker after some "km" from the start point in a DirectionsService's route?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my code :

```
var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
});
```

now, I'd like to put a marker after 200km from the point `origin: start` : is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that puts two markers on a route (one at 9.5km and one at 64.8km):

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_kmmarkersC.html

(so, yes, it is possible)

This example was created before the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) was released, and might be able to be re-written to use that.